# Update is not working for me ( i am on 11.10 )

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

it's been one week i am trying everything nothing is working.
I tryed to upgrade ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.10.

I tried the update manager but no sucess .

I also tried `update-manager -d` Not working
i tried `sudo update-manager -d` not working
I tried `sudo release-upgrade` not working

```
sudo apt-get update not working
sudo apt-get upgrade not working too so basically i am trying everything.
```

IN update manager , i did put the option for updating any version .
ANd i am on 11.10 ubuntu. So what else i can do ?

This is making me crazy .

Copy of the terminal bellow.
Please CAN Anyone can help me ?

PS: I do have update , but for runtime , c+ etc...( even today 15 updates about 11.10 )but nothing about the new release. And i do not have a cd player for updating.

```
administrator@BANG007:~$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
administrator@BANG007:~$ sudo update-manager -d
[sudo] password for administrator: 

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type aptdaemon+gtk3widgets+AptProgressDialog to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkVBox

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 97.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 103.

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type aptdaemon+gtk3widgets+AptProgressDialog to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkVBox

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(update-manager:10612): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

administrator@BANG007:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

administrator@BANG007:~$ sudo -apt-get update
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u
            user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] file ...

administrator@BANG007:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign ://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign ://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease                  
Ign ://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                  
Ign ://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease
Ign hp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease
Hit htp://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg                           
Hit htp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                               
Ign htp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                 
Ign ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                    
Ign ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed InRelease
Hit ttp://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release                     
Hit htp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                         
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                 
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg
Hit ttp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed Release.gpg
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                      
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release              
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release            
Hit ttp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release                          
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release             
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed Release             
Hit ttp://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Sources
Hit ttp://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages        
Ign ttp://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner TranslationIndex     
Hit ttp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                     
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources                    
Hit ttp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                        
Ign ttp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex            
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                 
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources          
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources            
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages          
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex        
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Sources                  
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Sources              
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Get:1 ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_GB [69.0 kB]    
Hit htp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                              
Hit htp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages                        
Ign htp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign htp://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en_GB             
Ign htp://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en                
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                   
Get:2 ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en_GB [68.5 kB]
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en
Get:3 ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en_GB [1,937 B]
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en
Get:4 ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en_GB [4,365 B]
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign htp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_GB                    
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Sources
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Sources
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Sources
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit htp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hitttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Ign ttp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                       
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Sources
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Sources           
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources             
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages           
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages       
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hitht
p://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/restricted Sources
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/main Sources
Hithtp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/multiverse Sources
Hit tp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/universe Sources
Hit tp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit tp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/main i386 Packages           
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/main TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/restricted TranslationIndex  
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/universe TranslationIndex    
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/main Translation-en          
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/restricted Translation-en    
Hit ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed/universe Translation-en      
Ign ttp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_GB                    
Ignttp://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en
Fetched 144 kB in 0s (199 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry htp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

administrator@BANG007:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
administrator@BANG007:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
administrator@BANG007:~$
```

Comment: You haven't tried 

    `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-manager --dist-upgrade
```